# How save image into models after create new image with pillow in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views, python-imaging-library

In first, I create a image with pillow library and save into media file,
now , I want save in to Temporary's model but does not save file.

**model:**

```
class TemporaryImage(models.Model):

        image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='temporary_images', verbose_name=_('image'))

        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('Temporary image')
            verbose_name_plural = _('Temporary images')
```

**View:**

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', (1024, 800), (255, 255, 255, 0)) 
image.save("media/output.png")
mediaPathImage = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/output.png'
print('media path : ', mediaPathImage)
Tobj = TemporaryImage()

Tobj.image = mediaPathImage
Tobj.save()
```

in this picture:
`no file chosen`
https://imge.to/i/ytogF

Comment: First of all: use the same variable inside the save function and the line `Tobj.image = mediaPathImage`, so you know 100% sure they are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the file to the right place then set the filename to your imagefield

```
image = Image.new('RGBA', (1024, 800), (255, 255, 255, 0))
filename = something sensible because they cannot all be saved to output.png
filepath = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/temporary_images/' + filename
image.save(filepath)
Tobj = TemporaryImage()
Tobj.image.name = filepath
Tobj.save()
```

Comment: I test but does not work: after click url -->     https://imge.to/i/yaZcj

Comment: I change `Tobj.image.name=('/temorary_images/' + filename)`    and successful worked thanks HenryM